# How do I add a delimiter to the returned value, and give delimiter a default value?

Tags: javascript, string, repeat, delimiter

The issue I am having, I need to alter this code in order to add a delimiter to the returned value, AND give delimter a deafult value.
I tried a few ifs however very unecessary  and got myself extreamly confused.

```
var stringRepeater = function (string, times, delimiter) {
var repeatedString = string;

for (var i = 1; i < times; i++) {
 repeatedString += string;
  }
return repeatedString;
}
```

=================This would be the output if working correctly================

```
console.log(stringRepeater("hi", 3, ",") === "hi,hi,hi");
// -> true
console.log(stringRepeater("hi", 3) === "hi hi hi");
// -> true
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question. We can answer questions but we wont give direct solutions. What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close. You can prepend the delimiter inside the loop and include a default parameter if it's unspecified to match your desired result:

```js
var stringRepeater = function (string, times, delimiter=" ") {
  //                                                   ^^^^
  var repeatedString = string;

  for (var i = 1; i < times; i++) {
    repeatedString += delimiter + string;
    //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }

  return repeatedString;
};

console.log(stringRepeater("hi", 3, ",") === "hi,hi,hi");
console.log(stringRepeater("hi", 3) === "hi hi hi");
```

Careful for an edge case when `times < 1`--you'll still wind up with one repeat. You could throw an exception or return an empty string if you wish.

Alternately, you can use the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) constructor to build an array of a certain length, [`.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) the array with string `s`, then [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array using the parameter delimiter (or `" "` if no delimiter was specified).

```
const stringRepeater = (s, times, delim=" ") =>  
  Array(times).fill(s).join(delim)
;
```

Another similar function worth knowing about is [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat), which almost does what you want, but not quite because it'd have a dangling delimiter, so you have to [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) it off:

```
const stringRepeater = (s, times, delim=" ") =>  
  (s + delim).repeat(times).slice(0, -delim.length)
;
```

Comment: if(helped me) { 
say Thanks!
} else {
nothing
}

output: THANKS! :D